# for loop over 20 data frames on each day simultaneously

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following data structure (still subject to changes):

```
pp = ([Pair1, Pair2, Pair3, ..., Pair25])
```

Each Pair has has the following format:

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 DatetimeIndex: 2016 entries, 2005-09-19 00:00:00 to 2013-09-12 00:00:00
 Data columns (total 2 columns):
 CA      2016  non-null values
 Na      2016  non-null values
```

I have lots of functions which need to be applied on each day for each DataFrame. However, the For-Loop may not run step-by-step such as for Pair1, Pair2, Pair3. The For-loop should rather run each day, for example:

```
 2005-09-19: do function for each pair!
 2005-09-20  and continue
 2005-09-21 
 2005-09-22
```

Is there a way to do that or do I need to completely change my data structure as well as codes?

**Update 1**

This where I am right now, however, is it efficient?

```
for i in range(len(ps[1])):
    for row in ps:
    print row[i:i+1]


                 A      C               DE
Date                                       
2005-09-19 -0.600021  4.649857            3
                 A     G                DE
Date                                      
2005-09-19 -0.600021  6.39693     0.105716
                 A     W                DE
Date                                       
2005-09-19 -0.600021  6.950815            5
                 A      C               DE
Date                                      
2005-09-20 -0.59711  4.637831            3
                 A      G               DE
Date                                       
2005-09-20 -0.59711  6.396263     0.109079
                 A     W                 DE
Date                                      
2005-09-20 -0.59711  6.951772            5
                 A      C                DE
Date                                       
2005-09-21 -0.594207  4.641213            3
                 A     G                 DE
Date                                          
2005-09-21 -0.594207  6.40059     0.109055
                 A     W                DE
Date                                       
2005-09-21 -0.594207  6.955593            5
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no reason they need to be separate data frames you should combine them into one dataframe with a multi index or simply a column indicating which pair they belong to.  Then you can group by to perform your function applications.

```
DF.groupby(['Date','pair']).apply(function)
```